# How to obtain polynomial coefficients from boundary conditions?

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I want to design a nozzle with its wall shape defined by a 7th order polynomial. The parameter I want to vary is its inflection point i

$y=ax^7+ bx^6+ ...+ gx + k$

I have the following boundary conditions:
$y(x=0)=h , y'(x=0)=0 , y''(x=0)=0 , y'(x=i)=0 , y(x=l)=0 , y'(x=l)=0 , y''(x=l)=0$

where h is the nozzle inlet radius - nozzle exit radius, and i is the axial location of the inflection point and l is the length of the nozzle.

I found a paper where the same problem was done with a 6th order polynomial and they found the coefficients using a matrix equation. I don't know how they got it but I would like to create a similar matrix equation to obtain the  coefficients for my 7th order polynomial

I have screenshots below and a reference for the paper: Sargison J E, Walker G J, and Rossi R, 2004. Design and Calibration of a Wind Tunnel with a
Two Dimensional Contraction (Proceedings of the 15th Australasian Fluid Mechanics Conference)
[Screenshot1 of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W19Z6.png)
[screenshot2 of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGNMV.png)
[screenshot3 of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVs5H.png)

Comment: But you have 8 unknowns, and only seven conditions. In the paper you quote, they have 7 unknowns and 7 conditions. So a 7×7 matrix to solve a classical AX=B (with X the vector of polynomial coefficient, the unknowns; B the left hand part of the conditions; and A the coefficient of the unknown in the right hand parts of the conditions, which are all linear combinations of those coefficients)

Answer (score 1):

Let us first compute the first and second derivatives:
$$ y'(x) = 7ax^6+6bx^5+5cx^4+4dx^3+3ex^2+2fx+g$$
and
$$ y''(x) = 42ax^5+30bx^4+20cx^3+12dx^2+6ex+2f.$$
Subsequently, we investigate what the boundary condition tell us:

1. $h = y(0) = k \implies k = h$.
2. Note that $0 = y'(0) = g \implies g =0$.
3. $ 0 =  y''(0) = 2f \implies f =0 $.
4. Using that $k = h$ and $f=g=0$, note that $ 0 = y(l) = al^7+bl^6+cl^5+dl^4+el^3+h$.
5. Using that $f= g = 0$, note that $0 = y'(i) = 7ai^6+6bi^5+5ci^4+4di^3+3ei^2$.
6. Similarly to 5., $0 = y'(l) = 7al^6+6bl^5+5cl^4+4dl^3+3el^2$.
7. Finally, $0 = y''(l) = 42al^5+30bl^4+20cl^3+12dl^2+6el$.

The matrix equation you're looking for is then
$$\begin{bmatrix} 42l^5 & 30l^4 & 20l^3 & 12l^2 & 6l \\
  6l^6 & 5l^5 & 4l^3 & 3l^2  & 0 \\
l^7 & l^6 & l^5 & l^4 & l^3 \\
6i^6 & 5i^5 & 4i^3 & 3i^2  & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\\ d \\ e \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -h \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$